# How to test a Laravel project for duration of requests

Tags: laravel, automated-tests

In a headless Laravel project we use unit and feature test.

The unit and feature tests checks the input and output of the requests and the methodes but they won't check the duration of the requests, methods or queries.

What is the best approach in Laravel for testing the duration of the requests or methods with millions of records in the database?

Comment: you could use microtime() function to mesure the duration of the request

Comment: But how to quickly setup 1.000.000 records in the test?

Comment: You can use a factory `factory(User::class, 1000000)->create();`, you will need to create that factory in database/factories, see the laravel docs for that https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing